# Trying to create web page links that will launch a Perl script

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, zoneminder

I am using a Ubuntu server with Apache2 and Zoneminder (a security camera program). I have one camera (but eventually will be three) that has pan tilt and zoom (PTZ). In the Zoneminder program (PHP web based interface), through navigation through the pages you can get a window that has a control for the PTZ. It uses a bunch of calls to different PHP pages to create this page and you can click a preset button and have the camera go to the location on set to the preset.

The cameras I will have set up will have two locations that will be used that I will call Security and Open. I want to create links that I can click and it will send the command without having to go through navigating to the control window.

I have found that when you get to the proper area in zoneminder for the camera's PTZ and press the "1" button the website sends the command

```
/usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl --preset=1 --command=presetGoto --id=3
```

which can be run from a terminal on the Ubuntu server and does set the camera to the proper location.

**UPDATE EDIT 3:** (This is what I am going with now so I removed all the data from the other attempts to clean up this post)

Trying something completely different and I have almost got it to work the way I want. I created two new files called `security.pl` and `open.pl` .. now in the `/usr/lib/zoneminder/cgi-bin`.. this is what I have so far for security.pl (open.pl is identical but with the different preset of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @command1 = ("/usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl", "--preset=1", "--command=presetGoto", "--id=3");
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<br><br><center><a href=javascript:history.back()>BACK</a></center>";
system(@command1);
```

and in the `montage.php and console.php` the links I add to make this function is:

```
<a href="cgi-bin/security.pl">Security</a>
```

This approach works and does change camera locations on one click the only problem I'm having now is this will leave a blank page with a back link showing the direct link to the perl script in the address bar.

This will work for me but ultimately I would like the security/open.pl script to automatically run the "back" link so it would run the command and return to the page that was clicked.

I have tried `print redirect(-url => 'javascript:history.back()');` in place of the `<a href=javascript:history.back()>` line but that just leaves me with a blank page and the camera does not move

Sorry about all this crazyness... but I'm close... The way its set up now does work and should be easily expanded if I add additional cameras, it would just be improved if I didn't have the blank page with a back link and it would just automatically return to the page (without having to hardcode the address because it will be linked in different pages and sometimes accessed from a local address and sometimes from an internet address).

I also notice one 'security' issue with this approach.. if you know the name and location of the script.. it bypasses the zoneminder login so anyone can change camera locations (lol guess I wont be using the names I used in this post just in case)

For my situation... the risk is low and it was hard enough for me to come up with this much.. I'm sure figuring out how to have it check to see if the user clicking that link is authorized to do so in Zoneminder.. so that anyone entering the link in a browser without already being logged into zoneminder would fail to function..would be even more difficult.

I suppose I will have to dig into the PHP and find out what the "controls" php has that checks this before it allows it and then figure out the way to properly add it to the perl script to make it load a page that does the proper check then if it passes runs the command. But that's for another time.

Comment: Are you able to create the web page on Ubuntu?

Comment: basically Im using the 'montage.php" page already  and just trying to add a link that will send that command. I haven't had any success on modifying the page with a link that functions. I know I have to create a separate php page or something to make a "function" then use something like `<a href="#" onclick="functionName()">` added to the montage page to "call" the command .. I just don't know the syntax or exactly what the process needs to function properly

Comment: You need to write a JavaScript function that will start your Perl command. It can be executed from a form button through the `onclick` attribute. But you seem to know so very little about anything that it's hard to guess what help could be useful. I think you have taken on far too much without expecting to put any time into studying the technology that you hope to use. You can't write a computer system by searching for likely--looking pieces of code on the internet and making changes to them by guesswork.

Comment: @Borodin you would be surprised what you can do with basic understanding, code snippets you get on the net from different situations and then making it work for your situation.  I asked here because I was hoping someone would know an easy way to do it and could share... I was putting in the time as you can see (sorry if I found that comment a bit rude) and was able to fix it on my own eventually .. it didn't hurt to ask though, someone may have saved me the days I spent figuring out a way that works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK.. I was finally able to get what I wanted so I figured with as much time spent I should relay the information

I got it to work by using the following perl script for `security.pl` and `open.pl` placed in `/usr/lib/zoneminder/cgi-bin` ..as for my post I will only put the security.pl here because open.pl is the same thing with the preset changed.

security.pl:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 my @command1 = ("/usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl", "--preset=1", "--command=presetGoto", "--id=3");
 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 system(@command1);
 print qq!<script>
 window.close()
 </script>!;
```

and the links I added to montage.php and console.php:

```
 <a href="cgi-bin/open.pl" target="popup">open</a>
 <a href="cgi-bin/security.pl" target="popup">Security</a>
```

this will launch a popup window and run the needed command then close the window leaving the montage/console screen untouched so no need for "back"

Its been a long road .. there is still the security issue I have to deal with in the future but as of now this is functioning as I wanted... eventually I will be able to figure out the rest :D thanks @Ricardo for your try

Answer (score 0):

To make that work i will do something like this:

```
<?php
    $command = '--command=presetGoto';
    $cam1 = '--id=3';

    function setOpen() {
        $preset = '--preset=1';
        exec("/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl $preset $command $cam1");
    } 

    function setSecurity() {
        $preset = '--preset=2';
        exec("/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl $preset $command $cam1");
    } 

    if (isset($_GET['setSecurity'])) {
        setSecurity();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['setOpen'])) {
        setOpen();
    }
?>
```

and modify this two lines like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="custom.php?setOpen=true">Open</a>
<a href="" onclick="custom.php?setSecurity=true">Security</a>
```

Comment: I don't get the undefined error but now I have a new error  and not sure why  .. now I get Unexpected end of input... I must have something else wrong in the function/exec :(

Comment: These errors usually appear when you have not enough or to many brackets. Make sure all your functions are closed.

Comment: yeah I checked I have all matching brackets and none that are out of place :( .. I tried the command in a terminal with the full line (perl included) and it failed .. so I edited the line to read `exec(/usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl $preset $command $cam1');` because as stated above that line does run in terminal (with the variables filled in of course) but still getting the same error

Comment: how about shell_exec(). Also make sure that the script has the correct privileges. chmod +x /usr/bin/zmcontrol.pl

Comment: Thanks for trying but same issue and yes it is marked executable already was one of the first things I check :( at least I'm further than I was

Comment: Sorry @Ricardo I went in a different direction so you can probably delete this answer because I'm not using that code anymore